# Generating function by Partial fraction expansion

Tags: probability, generating-functions

> Suppose then that the generating function is of the form:
>   $P(s)=U(s)/V(s)$. Where $U$ and $V$ are polynomials without common roots. For simplicity let us first assume that the degree of $U$ is lower than the degree of $V$, say $m$. Moreover, suppose that the equation $V(s) = 0$ has $m$ distinct roots $s_1, s_2, ... ,s_m$. Then $V(s)=(s-s_1)(s-s_2)...(s-s_m)$.
>
> It  can be decomposed into partial
>   fractions $P(s)=\frac{z_1}{(s_1-s)}+...+\frac{z_m}{(s_m-s)}$. Where $z_1,...z_m$ are constants. Multiply by $s_1-s$ as $s->s_1$ then
>   $(s_1-s)P(s)=\frac{-U_s}{(s-s_2)(s-s_3)...(s-s_m)}$. As $s->s_1$ the denomiator tends to $V'(s_1)$.

Why the denominator tends to $V'(s_1)$? I can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the derivative at a point $s_1$ is

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow s_1}\frac{V(x)-V(s_1)}{x-s_1}$$

Comment: Um... Yes and what?

Comment: Holy Molly! Thank you ))

Comment: Glad it clicked :)